# Laravel CSV importer Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, csv

I am importing a csv file from my laravel project to store the data in mySQL.
But i am getting the error : Undefined offset: 1

Laravel is pointing out the error:

```
// Insert to MySQL database
$importData_arr = array();
          $i = 0;

          while (($filedata = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
             $num = count($filedata );
             
             // Skip first row (Remove below comment if you want to skip the first row)
             /*if($i == 0){
                $i++;
                continue; 
             }*/
             for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                $importData_arr[$i][] = $filedata [$c];
             }
             $i++;
          }
          fclose($file);

          // Insert to MySQL database
          foreach($importData_arr as $importData){

            $insertData = array(
               "username"=>$importData[1],
               "name"=>$importData[2],
               "gender"=>$importData[3],
               "email"=>$importData[4]);
            Page::insertData($insertData);

          }
```

I have tried makiing the array as [1],[2],[3],[4] instead. makes no difference.

in the csv file i have 4 columns that stores title, price, inStock, imageURL.

in my Migration file, i have the following:

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('Rims', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('title');
     $table->float('price');
     $table->boolean('inStock');
     $table->string('imageURL');
     $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

Comment: how about you inspect `$importData` and see what keys it does have

Comment: @lagbox i have edited my code, to show that i should be creating the array keys from what is defined in the insertdata array?

Comment: just dump `$importData` and take a look at what it has in it ... instead of guessing

Comment: @lagbox When trying to var_dump($importData) from my index, i get error on : Undefined variable: importData (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/index.blade.php)

never used it before, and quite new to laravel. how would you do it?

Comment: dump it where you have actually created it and are using it ... the `foreach` ... this is all just PHP, nothing Laravel related here yet

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "Super FÆLG;830;0;/images/fælg1.jpg" } - so everything is in 0? thats because its csv? shouldnt it seperate between every ";" since thats my seperator

Comment: and yet you defined your separator/delimiter as `','` (3rd argument to `fgetcsv`)

Comment: Thank you very much, after cmpletion i use return Redirect::action('RimsUploadController@index'); is this wrong for newer versions of laravel? since it does not accept this call

Comment: you can redirect to actions, you will just have to use the FQCN to the controller, otherwise you would have to set a variable in the RouteServiceProvider to prefix namespaces when generating URLs to actions